# How can I get a continuous piecewise polynomial curve, with a turning point (not differentiable)?

Tags: algebraic-curves, curves, bezier-curve

I would like to make a curve which has turning point(x,y).

```
 y= x^2*2 for x<= 0.5

 y= 1-(1-x)^2*2 for x> 0.5
```

and still have a smooth S-shaped curve, where the slope is continuous on both sides of the turning point.

How can I make the equation as simple and straightforward as possible?

Comment: You need to make sure that the values and first derivatives of the constituents you use are the same at the glueing point. Which you did. What do you want to achieve beyond this?

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen : I want to achive making a simple equation curve with S shape and turning point(a,b).

Answer (score 1):

Differentiating your first function $y=2x^2$ gives $y'=4x$. Evaluating at $x=1/2$, gives $y'=2$.

Differentiating your second function $y=-2x^2+4x-1$ gives $y'=-4x+4$. Evaluating at $x=1/2$, gives $y'=2$.

You picked a pair of curves whose derivatives are lines and only intersect at the point you have chosen.

Choose simpler functions and pick a point of intersection; check the derivatives.

Edit: There are infinitely many lines that will work. Consider $y=x$ and $y=-x$. They have derivatives 1 and -1 everywhere. They intersect at (0,0). According to what you have said, this is a "turning point."

Comment: Thanks for letting me. But I can't understand You picked a pair of curves whose derivatives are lines and only intersect at the point you have chosen. 

Choose simpler functions and pick a point of intersection; check the derivatives. What do you mean?  This is so silly but I 'm not familiar with math. So please let me know my question with mercy.